# QML encapsulation without creating new files

Tags: qt, qml, encapsulation, qtquick2

Let's consider the following example:

```
ColumnLayout
{
    spacing: 10
    Label { color: "green"; text: "one text" }
    Label { color: "green"; text: "another text" }
    Label { color: "green"; text: "some text" }
}
```

It would be great to create a type. One could create a file `GreenLabel.qml`

```
Label { color: "green" }
```

and do something like this:

```
ColumnLayout
{
    spacing: 10
    GreenLabel { text: "one text" }
    GreenLabel { text: "another text" }
    GreenLabel { text: "some text" }
}
```

Can this be done without creating another file?

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. At best, you can define a new type inside a `Component` element, and then use a `Loader` or a manual dynamic instantiation to create an object out of the type prototype.

Answer (score 3):

In a scenario like yours you might as well consider using a `Repeater` and put the text strings in its model